# request time out and specifed server couldn't be found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, cllocationmanager

I am seeing this wired problem where when i launch my app i get continuous(4-5 times) error message sometime it says

1. "data connection cannot be established since a call is currently active" there is no active call
2. The request timed out
3. A server with the specified hostname could not be found.

and when you click ok, couple of times the error message goes away and the app works without any problem.

I am doing two things when the app launches, i start updating the current location using the CLLocationManager and once i get the location I make two async call using NSURLConnection, i  see that didFailWithError method in my NSURLConnection delegate method getting called, 
all the message comes from there, so what i am trying to figure out is

1. **Why it is coming, my server is fine i have proper internet connection ( I am on wifi not on cell phone data)**
2. **Why it comes so many times, i am firing only two request.**

It starts behaving a bad launch. I was wondering if it needs some warm up time or something like that. I would like to display the error message but not all of them probably one is fine like even if there is no data connection, displaying so many times will annoy the user.

Here is the code in my didFailWithError.

```
 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                     message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error code is %d", [error code]]
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alertView show];
  [alertView release];
```

One more question how do i print the actual error message instead of this cryptic error code.

Thanks for helping me out.

[EDIT] code for establishing the connection

```
    NSURL *getURL = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];   

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

//add our HTTP headers and URL
[request setValue: @ "plain/text" forHTTPHeaderField : @"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setURL : getURL];

NSURLConnection* urlConnection =
   [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                    delegate:delegate  
                            startImmediately:YES] autorelease];
```

Yogesh

Comment: __I am capturing the error and displaying it with UIAlertView__ - I guess that's where the error messages are coming from then?

Comment: Try to disable the network on your iPhone simulator and see if it throws the same error. Then you'd know it has something to do with the network.

Comment: Do you have some sample code so we can help better?

Comment: @dean, so when i say capturing and displaying it with UIAlertView I am saying that's why i know that it is not coming from there

Comment: @Andrei, good suggestion, i will try that out

Comment: @jeff i am not sure what code should i put here

Comment: I don't get it - you say that there are two error messages popping up - that's what a UIAlertView is! Can you post a screenshot of the error message and add the code in your didFailWithError: to your question please?

Comment: @dean, yes those alert message are popping up from my didFailWithError method, so now I am wondering even though i am connected on wifi, and my server is responding properly why does this error message happnes

Comment: @Andrei, yes it pops up when there is no internet connection but now I am wondering why it is popping up even though there is an internet connection

Comment: Just because your phone thinks that there is a connection doesn't mean that there is one :) 3G is sometimes unreliable so requests might just not work.

Comment: @dean so as I said i am on wifi not on 3G, i understand that connection are not reliable, so probably what I am trying to understand is when should I display this error message and when not, displaying it so many times will bother user

Comment: Post the code for establishing the connection. Is the server corporate/inhouse or on the public Internet? Are you using the FQDN? Are there limitations on the WiFi (like a firewall)? Can you browse to the same server via Safari (if applicable)?

Comment: @Seva it is on the public internet, i can access it via Safari, there are no limitation on WiFi, I will post the code for establishing the connection in a while

Comment: @Seva, I have added the code for establishing the connection

Comment: Also, how do you initialize the URL? You can mask servername if you wish...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer for this, actually i have signficantLocationChange thing on, and what is happening is when the app wakes after due to the signficantLocationChange, app is suppose to make a server call to get some information, and what is happening is when the app wakes up there are situation when there is no data connection available, so all the errors are getting pilled up, and when the user opens the app he see all of that.

Answer (score 1):

You may print the actual error message using the following lines:

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *) error {
     NSLog(@"localizedDescription%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

You will have to implement the above method wherever you make your `NSURLConnection`.

I am new on Stack Overflow. So, if have not followed any rule/custom while answering above question, please point out.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `Content-Type: text/plain` request header right away. Unless you're submitting POST data along, the request doesn't have a content-type. And GET requests are not supposed to contain POST data.

Comment: i am not submitting POST data, ok I can get rid of Content-Type: but is it that which causes this problem

Comment: No idea. But Content-type on GET request is wrong. What's the URL, anyway?